# Create constructor with block in java

Tags: java, constructor

In Android, there is a class called Runnable, and to get an instance of it, the code is like this:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //do whatever here
    }
}
```

How can I do this wit my own class?

So for example:

```
package com.tylerr147.constructorThingy;
public class Whatever {
    //do whatever for the cunstructor here
}
```

and

```
package com.tylerr147.constructorThingy;
public class OtherClass {
    Whatever w = new Whatever() {
        @Override
        public void WhateverRun() {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated
Thanks!

Comment: Please adhere to the Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public interface Whatever {
    public void myMethod();
}
```

You can state your `Whatever` class to interface, and you can new and **implement** your method, like:

```
Whatever w = new Whatever () {
   @Override
   public void myMethod() {
    ...
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's what he's asking.  It sounds to me like he's trying to override a constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: @chengpohi And you just taught me what an interface is! I never understood it when there was something like `public void something();`

Comment: @ajb, I think he is unclear how to use `interface` in **Java**, so I just want to explain this to him, hope it's helpful for him.

Comment: @ajb He answered my question exactly

Answer (score 1):

Runnable is just an interface with must overridden method run

If you want to use @override you should make your Whatever to be an interface with whateverrun method.

```
public interface Whatever {
    public void WhateverRun();
}

   Whatever w = new Whatever () {
   @Override
   public void WhateverRun() {
    ...
   }
}
```